# Keep Body while changing the title

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am working with JS bookmarklets and I am playing around with`javascript:document.title = "WHATEVAH"`. However, when I use that by itself, it removes all content on the page. So then I tried `javascript:document.title = "WHATEVAH";document.body.innerHTML = document.body;` but that didn't work either. Please explain what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return undefined at the end, otherwise it's going to navigate to a blank page. A common way of doing it is to do:

```
javascript:document.title = "WHATEVAH"; void 0;
```

Comment: Could you please explain what "void 0;" does? I am just learning JS

Comment: @Konstrictor [It's just a shorter way to write `;undefined;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)